# Printing an arraylist in reverse order

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, textview

I have a textview with buttons on each side, then I linked an ArrayList of strings to the textview, now when clicking the right button views the text of the next element and so on.! I did that, but couldn't reverse the process from the left button..!

- Element 0 > "text 0"
- Element 1 > "text 1"
- Element 2 > "text 2"
- Element 3 > "text 3"

By default the text is showing the first element "text 0", when I click the right button is shows "text 1" ...etc. when it reaches the last index it loops again from the start.!

**What I want is** to show the previous element when the left button is clicked..!
so if the the textview is showing "text 2" , once left button clicked "text 1" must show..and so on..! when the index is 0 and left button clicked it should show the last element and loop again..!???

Here's the code for the right button which works fine with the first scenario!

```
 // inside the onClick ..
 public int viewIndex = 0;

 if (viewIndex == TxtList.size()) {
      viewIndex = 0;
    }
    txt.setText(TxtList.get(viewIndex));
    viewIndex++;
```

Comment: is the `viewIndex` shared for both listeners? Or every listener has it's own `vewIndex` member

Comment: it's shared, `viewIndex` is a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in your set onclick listener on both buttons

```
leftBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
rightBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
int index = 0;
```

now in your onClick method

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.left:
    if(index!=0){
     index--;
     }else { 
        // this else is important because when the index=0, it must show the
       //last element of the array when swiped again..! and begin the cycle over again..!  
      index= TextList.size();
      index--;
    }
    textView.setText(TextList.get(index));
    break;

   case R.id.right:
     index++;
    if(index>=TextList.size()){
    index=0;
    }
 textView.setText(TextList.get(index));
    break;

 }}
```

Comment: @Sandeep your code works.. thanks a lot man, but i've added the `else` to make the solution more optimal.. see the comment and tell me what u think..!

Comment: can u guys upvote the question so the (-1) go away..!plz